# Unable to get $ to print sign after my variable prints in C++

Tags: c++

I keep getting this error message:

```
exit status 1

main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:31:68: error: unable to find string literal operator 'operator""endl' 
with 'const char [3]', 'long unsigned int' arguments

At cout<< "The total purchase value amount is ">>totalPurchase<<"$."endl;
```

Sorry I'm new to programming and I cannot figure out how to resolve this, I know its a simple thing. I'm just trying to get a $. behind my values when the data prints to the user so it looks nicely formatted. Any explanation of what im doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.
If i delete the "$." part it works just fine but it displays to the user as just a number instead of a dollar value.

Thank you for any help!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {

//The part is to declare our constants and variables

double totalPurchase;
double calcstatetax;
double calccountytax;
double totalsalestax;
double ultimatevalue;
double statetax = .04;
double countytax = .02;


//This part is to allow the user to input information

  cout << "Enter the amount of the purchase.";
  cin >> totalPurchase;

    //This part is our algorithm calculating the needed values

    calcstatetax = totalPurchase*statetax;
    calccountytax = totalPurchase*countytax;
    totalsalestax = calcstatetax+ calccountytax;
    ultimatevalue = totalsalestax+ totalPurchase;

      //This part displayes our calculated values to the user.

      cout<< "The total purchase value amount is "<<totalPurchase<<"$."endl;
      cout<< "The calculated state tax is "<<calcstatetax<<endl;
      cout<< "The calculated county tax is "<<calccountytax<<endl;
      cout<< "The total sales tax is "<<totalsalestax<<endl;
      cout<< "The total value of the purchase including the combined sales tax is "<<ultimatevalue<<endl;
```

Comment: I’ll bet you could remove 95% of that code and still show the problem.

Comment: A quick note about `endl`. In addition to placing an end of line character in the stream's buffer, `endl` also flushes the buffer to the underlying medium. This can be quite an expensive operation depending on the nature of that underlying medium. You want to do it as infrequently as possible. If you need to make sure a console write gets to the user before they can continue, a prompt for input for example, use `endl` to force the buffer to be written to the screen. Otherwise, use the newline character, `'\n`'.

Answer (score 1):

> main.cpp: In function 'int main()': main.cpp:31:68: error: unable to find string literal operator 'operator""endl' with 'const char [3]', 'long unsigned int' arguments

You forgot to add `<<` operator before the last `endl`:

Replace:

```
cout<< "The total purchase value amount is "<<totalPurchase<<"$."endl;
```

with:

```
cout<< "The total purchase value amount is "<<totalPurchase<<"$." << endl;
```

[Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/YqTFUUWJBCrVIkhG)